# ¿Cómo desarrollar con funciones y programación modular? C++

Tags: c++

¿Cómo se puede hacer que al encontrar el numero menor del primer vector comience a pegar al segundo vector desde la posición inicial hasta el numero que contiene el menor numero?

Ejemplo:

1 vector a y b

```
A = 17 2 9 25 1 7 24 5 12 10
B = 11 23 4 7 15 13
```

Respuesta:

```
B = 11 23 4 7 15 13 17 2 9 25 1
```

---

Código:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int i;
void IngresarDatosVectorA(int a[50],int &n);
void IngresarDatosVectorB(int b[50],int &x);
void mostrarVectorA(int a[50],int n);
void mostrarVectorB(int b[50],int x);
//void Mostrar(int a[50],int n ,int r);
int PosicionMenor(int a[50],int n);
void unir(int n,int x,int a[50],int b[50],int &r,int c[50]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  int a[50];
  int b[50];
  int c[50];
  int r,x,s,n,q,menor;
  IngresarDatosVectorA(a,n);
  IngresarDatosVectorB(b,x);
  mostrarVectorA(a,n);
  mostrarVectorB(b,x);
  //Mostrar(a,n,r); 
  r=PosicionMenor(a,n);  
  unir(n,x,a,b,r,c);
  // mostrarResultado(b,x);

  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void IngresarDatosVectorA(int a[50],int &n){

  cout<<"Ingrese Cantidad de elementos del Vector A: ";cin>>n;
  for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese valor del Vector A "<<i+1<<" : ";
    cin>>a[i];         
  }  
}

void IngresarDatosVectorB(int b[50],int &x){

  cout<<"Ingrese Cantidad de elementos del Vector B ";cin>>x;
  for (i=0;i<x;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese valor del Vector B"<<i+1<<" : ";
    cin>>b[i];         
  }  
}

void mostrarVectorA(int a[50],int n){
  cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl;
  for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<a[i]<<endl;
    setw(3);     
  } 
  cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl; 
}

void mostrarVectorB(int b[50],int x){
  cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl;
  for (i=0;i<x;i++){
    cout<<b[i]<<endl;
    setw(3);     
  } 
  cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl; 
}

int PosicionMenor(int a[50],int n) {
  int posi,menor;
  menor=a[0];
  for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(a[i]<menor){
      menor=a[i];
      posi=i;
    }
  }
  return posi;
}
```

Comment: Exactamente, ¿ donde te has atascado ? Sería recomendable que pegaras el código que tienes hecho hasta ahora.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta por demasiado amplia. Parercen ejercicios de deberes y no ha intentado nada.

Comment: Creo que hay gente que no entiende la diferencia entre pedir ayuda a preguntas específicas y querer que les resulvan su tarea, debería ser cerrada la pregunta.

Comment: señores con respecto al primer ejercicio si lo he avanzado perdon por no cargar hasta donde me quede soy nuevo en el foro talvez no lei las normas que seria lo adecuado de un principiante.las discupas del caso me quede aqui lo que necesito es que me apoyen como puede hacer que al encontrar el numero menor del primer vector comienze a pegar al segundo vector desde la posicion inicial hasta el numero que contiene el menor numero.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un código más simple que resuelve tu problema

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>

using namespace std;

void IngresarDatosVectorA(vector<int> &myvectorA, int &n)
{
  int valor;
  cout<<"Ingrese Cantidad de elementos del Vector A: ";cin>>n;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese valor del Vector A "<<i+1<<" : ";
    cin >> valor;
    myvectorA.push_back(valor);         
  }  
}

void IngresarDatosVectorB(vector<int> &myvectorB, int &n)
{
  int valor;
  cout<<"Ingrese Cantidad de elementos del Vector B: ";cin>>n;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese valor del Vector B "<<i+1<<" : ";
    cin >> valor;
    myvectorB.push_back(valor);                  
  }  
}

vector<int> Resolver(vector<int> &myvectorA, vector<int> &myvectorB, int size1)
{
    int pivote = INT_MAX, posicion;
    for(int i=0; i<size1; i++)
    {
        if(myvectorA[i] < pivote)
        {
            pivote = myvectorA[i];
            posicion = i;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<=posicion; i++)
    {
        myvectorB.push_back(myvectorA[i]);
    }
    return myvectorB;
}

void ImprimirResultado(vector<int> vectorFinal)
{
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    for (it=vectorFinal.begin(); it<vectorFinal.end(); it++)
        cout << ' ' << *it;
}

int main()
{
    int size1, size2, posicion;
    vector<int> myvectorA, myvectorB, vectorFinal;
    IngresarDatosVectorA(myvectorA, size1);
    IngresarDatosVectorB(myvectorB, size2);
    vectorFinal = Resolver(myvectorA, myvectorB, size1);
    ImprimirResultado(vectorFinal);
    return 0;
}
```

Pruebalo con los inputs que quieras, con el ejemplo que pusiste si funciona.

Comment: es lo que necesitaba muchas gracias Maury Cortes por tu ayuda se soluciono mi problema.